# Turning on debug for the Spring Roo shell

Tags: debugging, logging, spring-roo

I would like to be able **to turn on the debug logging level for the Spring Roo Shell** so that I get the full stack trace if and when an error occurs.

Can anyone please advise on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there's the command:

```
roo> development mode --enabled true
```

http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-development-mode

I don't know if it shows a full stack trace or not when an error occurs.

Comment: this doesn't seem to change anything, is it logged in the console?

Comment: it does however work if i run the roo shell from the command line, and not from within STS